Is the red serge uniform worn by police in Nova Scotia in 1863 in a movie an anachronism?
The 1975 movie The Story of Adèle H, by director François Truffaut, is set mostly in Nova Scotia in 1863, when that province was a British colony and not yet a part of Canada.
A simple-minded stereotype teaches us that Canadian police officers wear red serge uniforms. (I know of a case where a man in Minnesota, told to expect a phone call from a Canadian federal bureaucrat asking for some information about certain international transactions, jokingly said "ok, I'll expect a man in a red uniform riding a horse." Such is the nature of stereotypes.) In fact, those are worn by the Royal Canadian Mounted Police on ceremonial occasions, and this web page seems to suggest they were introduced in the 1870s.
So in this movie, set in a time when Nova Scotia was not yet a part of Canada, a police officer wears the red serge uniform. Is that an anachronism – Truffaut exploiting a simple stereotype for an audience aware of the stereotype and ignorant of the history – or did police officers at that time and place wear red serge uniforms?

More to the  point: Did "police", in the modern sense, even exist in Nova Scotia in 1863? From History of Halifax Regional Police:  "October 1864: The Day Watch and Night Watch in Halifax merged to form the Halifax Police Department under Garrett Cotter, the first Chief of the Halifax Police Department. Six divisions were formed with five men assigned to each sergeant."

IMDB says this is a "goof" when asserting the Hypnotist has a plant in the audience who is "pretending to be a [Mountie]". Haven't seen it, but if that is the case then it is indeed an anachronism. There are other red uniforms in trailers etc. which seem to be different than what you are asking about.

@Yorik :  He wore a uniform like the one the Mounties wear on ceremonial occasions. But if a red serge uniform was standard in Nova Scotia in 1863, then that wouldn't mean he was pretending to be a Mountie, but that he was pretending to be a member of whichever body of persons wore red serge uniforms at that time and place. So a person writing at IMDB who doesn't know the early history of the RCMP would naturally think he was pretending to be a Mountie. The red uniforms in trailers were probably British military uniforms, since the British military is prominent in the movie.

On the other hand when the Onion (a newspaper that publishes parodies of news articles) quoted an officer of "the Royal Canadian Mounted Coast Guard," that was not a goof.

Note that modern ceremonial uniforms usually resemble the ordinary uniforms of an earlier era.
